# Inspect request body and header

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

Using the aiohttp Client, is it possible to inspect a request (header and body) before or after sending?

I am using aiohttp.ClientSession to make and send the request - but I'd like to see the header and body that actually got sent.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look on client tracing support: http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#client-tracing